# Why is an unused Symfony2 entity consuming so much performance?

Tags: performance, symfony, database-performance

For my Symfony2 webapp, I have created a data model consisting of 16 entities. Main entities are `User` and `Company`. There is another entity: `Location`.

There is no implemented functionality concerning the `Location`, so it's unused by now. (Will say: It is defined as a doctrine entity, but not implemented in any controller.)

I recently signed up for a monitoring service (NewRelic), which allows to check for database performance consumption. Funny thing: My `Location` entity, which I don't use **at all**, consumes most performance: It has the highest throughput and is the most time consuming entity in my database. (Besides `_session`, but don't notice that.)

[image]

All other entities listed in that monitoring app are entities, that are used in my app.

There are a couple of other entities that are defined but not implemented. And none of those entities are listed in my monitoring app.

May `Location` be a Symfony2-reserved entity name that - if used - will consume performance? Do you have any other explanations for this behaviour?

Comment: Do `User` and/or `Company` entities have relation to `Location` by any chance?

Comment: Yes, both have. But, for example, there is also a `Project` entity, which has relation to both. And that does not consume any db performance...

Comment: Which type of loading is set to those relations? `LAZY` (default) or `EAGER`? If it's `EAGER` that explains a lot. If it's `LAZY` I would assume that performance consumption is accounted to Proxy object management. As for the `Project` entity, you don't query it explicitly - thus no resources are consumed.

Comment: I didn't explicitly set different loading types for `Project` or `Location`. Why are there differences?

Comment: Do you interact with the `location` relationship in your views? i.e., `{{ company.location.propertyName }}`

Comment: No, no interaction at all. Neither in the controller, nor in the views.